# How to handle bootstrap tooltip with zoom out code?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have used zoom out(Scaling) code for increasing the area of my template.

And I have used tooltips on button but due to zoom css code, the tooltip is misplaced.

```
    body {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
        zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
        zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
    }
```

`<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide Sensitive Info">`

[image]

Any Suggestion how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to apply zoom to html tag. In my case it is working.

```
html {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8); /* Moz-browsers */
    zoom: 0.8; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
    zoom: 80%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I tried earlier and it worked that time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: When I add this style to my HTML tag I have design issues. So Kindly share an alternative solution here. Thank you. @dimonweb

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this script:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>
```

And call the button like this way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hide Sensitive Info">
    Hide sensitive Info
</button>
```

Comment: My Issue is that it is misplaced due to my zoom out CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

try adding to your tooltip

```
container: "body"
```

Bootstrap documentations on tooltip container props:

Appends the tooltip to a specific element. Example: container: 'body'. This option is particularly useful in that it allows you to position the tooltip in the flow of the document near the triggering element - which will prevent the tooltip from floating away from the triggering element during a window resize.

Comment: I am not getting how exactly to implement this. Can you provide any example?

Comment: Try with <button data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide Sensitive Info">

Comment: No Luck! Still same problem!